# COUNT of DISTINCT items in a column

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Here's the SQL that works (strangely) but still just returns the COUNT of all items, not the COUNT of DISTINCT items in the column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(columnName)) FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName
```

counts all rows in the table,

```
SELECT COUNT(columnName) FROM tableName
```

counts all the rows in the table where columnName is not null, and

```
SELECT (DISTINCT COUNT(columnName)) FROM tableName
```

counts all the rows in the table where columnName is both not null and distinct (i.e. no two the same)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(columnName)) FROM tableName
```

Is the second query (returning, say, 42), and the distinct gets applied after the rows are counted.

Answer (score 15):

You need

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnName) AS Cnt
FROM tableName;
```

The query in your question gets the `COUNT` (i.e. a result set with one row) then applies `Distinct` to that single row result which obviously has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM tableName);
```